# Proving if $x$ is rational then $\sqrt x$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification, rational-numbers

I'm trying to prove the statement: Let $x\in\mathbb R$. If $x$ is rational then $\sqrt x$ is irrational. I know that a number $x$ is rational if we can write it as $x=\frac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p, q$, where $q\neq 0$ and we say that $x$ is irrational if it is not rational. Here's what I have so far:

Let $x$ be a real number and let us assume that it is rational. By the definition of rational numbers, there exist integers $p,q$ with $q\neq 0$ such that $x=\frac{p}{q}$. Next, we will take the square root of $x$ which gets us $\sqrt x=\sqrt \frac{p}{q}$.

However, I'm lost on where to go from here. As I was working through the proof, I kind of realized that the statement might be false, so I was trying to think of counterexamples and the one I thought of was let $x=4$, which we can represent as $4=\frac{8}{2}$ and the $\sqrt 4=2$, which is rational. Am I going in the right direction? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Your counterexample is correct, the original claim is not true.

Comment: You can't prove it because it's obviously false. Your counterexample is correct (although you didn't really need to observe that $4=8/2$; any integer $n$ can be written $n=n/1$, so it is automatically rational).

Comment: @YiFan Yeah, I realize that after you pointed it out, I'm still new to proofs, so I tend to overthink things here and there. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square of any rational number, is a rational number whose square root is rational. So what you are trying to prove is false.

However it is true that a rational number $\frac pq$(in lowest terms) has an irrational square root, if and only if at least one of $p$ or $q$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: If both $p$ and $q$ are no perfect squares, then the square root might not be rational. For example, $\frac{2}{3}$ has irrational square root.

Comment: @KingLogic Corrected "any one" to "at least one". Is it fine now?

Comment: I think that's better.